# Pluggable assemblies locking while running MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a composite MVC3 Application using Ninject. It is based on plug and play concepts to provide the ability to build modules of your MVC application outside of your core MVC application.Each module is attached to this main MVC application and has it's own separate folder in main MVC application where the dll gets copied with supporting files like views,contents etc.

Using Ninject the module assemblies get loaded when the application starts and runs fine.The issue is when the application is running in IIS,the assemblies get locked and i cannot replace existing dll with the modified one.The only way I know is to restart the app pool.I don't want to restart the app pool,is there any other option to avoid dll locking and i can easily replace my dll.

Answer (score 0):

One method may be to "shadow" the assemblies and load them that way (This is what IIS does itself).  Essentially they are copied to a different, temporary location and loaded from *there* instead of the actual directory.  When the system detects a change in DLL in the original location (e.g. a new version has been copied), it can recycle the application pool, copy the newer Dlls in to the temporary location and load them again.

I am guessing you would need to implement something similar to update your dependent DLLs.  Note that, within an app-domain, you cannot *unload* an assembly.  That said, you can unload an app-domain.  In theory you could host the dlls in their own app-domain (allowing you to unload that domain when you detect a change), thereby avoiding restarting the actual application pool domain itself - but this all depends on how the system is architected and may not be desirable in your circumstance.